# What kind of worm is this in my food? (Tuna sandwich from canned tuna)

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]

Can I have some assistance identifying this worm which was in a tuna salad sandwich I purchased from a local co-op in Minneapolis MN?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a maggot (fly larvae) of some sort — see for example the following image:
[image: common green bottle fly maggot — image ©Richard Major]

That particular image is of a [common green bottle fly](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/livestock/flies/lucilia_sericata.htm) maggot, which has a distribution consistent with your posted location.